# Remove empty query strings from url

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to remove empty parameters from the url querystring before form submission.

form submission on a `GET` request:

```
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Search">
```

I've come across this example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        // Remove empty fields from GET forms

        // Change 'form' to class or ID of your specific form
        $("form").submit(function () {
            $(this).find(":input").filter(function () { return !this.value; }).attr("disabled", true);

            return true; // ensure form still submits
        });

        // Un-disable form fields when page loads, in case they click back after submission
        $("form").find(":input").prop("disabled", false);
    });
```

The issue I have with this is that it disables the input fields instead of just ignoring the empty ones. I don't want to disable inputs but rather ignore empty ones.

Is there a way I can achieve this? Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code does not submit elements, so you can't change it. If you would have Ajax request, then you can filter your inputs and form request with only valid inputs.

Comment: If the method is GET, you could of course create the resulting submission URL yourself.

Comment: @Justinas yes I've edited the post

Comment: You could just [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)  the result of the field filtering you are already doing there, to create the appropriate query string, and then “submit” the form by assigning that (plus the proper base address from the form action attribute, if any) as the new location.

Comment: The code snippet does precisely what you have requested in your question. So _why_ does it disable the fields before submitting the form programmatically? This: _Specifically, disabled inputs do not receive the click event, and disabled inputs are not submitted with the form._ from this [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefdisabled).

Comment: Additionally, the fields are re-activated after the form is submitted - so the premise that this is in some way bothersome is interesting.

Comment: @RandyCasburn the issue is that when I click search it disables the textboxes. I don't want that to happen. But the code filters the parameters based on a  'disabled' attributed. I want it to filter based on empty inputs instead.

Comment: Replace `return true;` with `$(this).submit()`